# Cant find a Div inside of my child repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Im trying to change the Visible of my Div, but im not being able to find it. Its seems because its inside of another Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uxPesquisaList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="uxQuestList_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Descricao")%></strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%--    Listagem de Respostas --%>
        <asp:Repeater ID="uxRespList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <div id="uxRespostaText" visible="false" runat="server"> ***I want to display this Div***
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="uxResposta" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Descricao")%>' />
                        </td>
                    </div>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My Code Behind

```
protected void uxQuestList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater rptRespostas = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("uxRespList"));

        QuestionarioPergunta pergunta = (QuestionarioPergunta)e.Item.DataItem;

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl uxRespostaText = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)e.Item.FindControl("uxRespostaText"); **I try this, but it always return NullExpection**

        if (pergunta.TipoPergunta == "Dissertativa")
        {
            uxRespostaText.Visible = true;
        }

        rptRespostas.DataSource = ctx.QuestionarioRespostas.Where(x => x.PergId == pergunta.Id).ToList();
        rptRespostas.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to look for the TextBox in each item of the inner Repeater. You can set the `ItemDataBound` event handler of `uxRespList` in the markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uxRespList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="uxRespList_ItemDataBound">
```

In code-behind, you bind the data of that inner Repeater in the event handler of the outer Repeater (as you already do in your code):

```
protected void uxQuestList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater rptRespostas = e.Item.FindControl("uxRespList") as Repeater;
        ...

        rptRespostas.DataSource = ...
        rptRespostas.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And you process each inner Repeater item after its data is bound:

```
protected void uxRespList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        TextBox uxRespostaText = e.Item.FindControl("uxRespostaText") as TextBox;
        ...
    }
}
```